# Adding child divs dynamically to a parent div doesn't make the parent div grow to accommodate the child divs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div on the main page:

```
<div id="Alerts" class="Alerts"><a class="handle" href=""></a></div>
```

I'm populating this div with others div at run time:

```
function CreateDivIncident(errorcode, name, address, lat, lng) {  
var div = CreateDefaultDiv('Alerts');  
var html = errorcode + '</b> Name:' + name + ' Address: ' + address;  
div.innerHTML = html;  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseover', function () { div.style.backgroundColor = '#55FFFF'; });  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseout', function () { div.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; });  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mouseup', function () { gmap.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)); });  
}

function CreateDefaultDiv(parent) {  
var div = document.createElement('div');  
div.style.marginBottom = '5px';  
div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';  
div.style.border = 'solid 1px';  
div.style.fontSize = "16px";  
div.style.fontFamily = "Arial";  
div.style.paddingRight = "5px";  
document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(div);  
return div;  
}
```

The new divs are showing and acting to clicks well but the parent div isn't growing its height correspondingly. The new divs are just "floating" above it.

What am I missing here? Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried this on your container? http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: When adding this divs manually, the parent div grow to fill them. Adding them dynamically doesn't make the parent grow. I've tried adding the clear: both; to the parent but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `float:left` css rule on `.Alerts` or `#Alerts`. Parent container will take the height and width. By using `border:1px solid red;` on your parent div and child divs you do testing, i mean which element is outside and which one is inside. By identifying the boundaries.

**Update:** Remove the height 110px;

Comment: I've tried adding the `float` tag to the parent, but no changes are made to it.

Comment: can you show me the working code or screen shot/fiddle on which we can see realtime situation.

Comment: The code is shown above, here is the css for the parent div: `.Alerts
{
    padding: 5px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    border: black 1px solid;
    direction: rtl;
    min-height: 98px;
}`. I'm calling the function using `RegisterStartupScript`.

Comment: can you show me a screen shot of your situation. because i am not able to execute the function in my system so i just added some div in parent div and its works perfect in my browser.

Comment: Here is a ![screenshot](http://i39.tinypic.com/35i65wh.png).  You can see that the child divs are placed outisde of the minimal height that the parent have.

Comment: i can see the situation in screen shot. You site is live or some where uploaded.

Comment: @toy4fun - still some problem is there please let me know. Now i can help you as you want because the real time situation is in front of me.

Comment: you can save the image right now by using right click of mouse and save image as. If your problem is solve than you can make the answer correct.

Comment: The height is added inline <div class="Alerts open" id="Alerts" style="line-height: 1; top: 99px; right: -3px; height: 110px; position: fixed;">  check you code. are you using any plugin for this functionality or check javasript from where this css is applying and remove the height your problem will solve. Did you save the image?

Comment: The code for the parent div is [here](http://www.serapha.com/test/scripts/tabslide.js). The `height` property came from there but I can't understand why it's working fine when adding divs manually and not when adding dynamically. I did save the images, thanks.

Comment: find the same code in tou js and try to comment 'height' . if(settings.tabLocation === 'left' || settings.tabLocation === 'right') {
            obj.css({
                'height' : properties.containerHeight,
                'top' : settings.topPos
            });

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Could you please remove the screen shot from your answer, thanks again.

Comment: Hello there, i think some one already remove the image, any ways i m happy and feeling glad to solve your problem.